# Odoo 10 - Retrieving the value of invoice sequence

Tags: odoo

I want to override the unlink method of account.invoice model.

Currently this method is:

```py
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    for invoice in self:
        if invoice.state not in ('draft', 'cancel'):
            raise UserError(
                _('You cannot delete an invoice which is not draft or cancelled. You should refund it instead.'))
        elif invoice.move_name:
            raise UserError(_(
                'You cannot delete an invoice after it has been validated (and received a number). You can set it back to "Draft" state and modify its content, then re-confirm it.'))
    return super(AccountInvoice, self).unlink()
```

If move_name has been assigned (i.e. a valid sequence was given to this invoice), it does not let you remove the invoice. 
While that is a perfect and impeccable accounting rule, it reflects poor understanding of real world operations of certain business, where you actually need to delete an invoice.

So I want to allow users to delete last invoice, even if it was raised.

In order to do that, programmatically (inside the python erase method) the following actions are needed:

1. identify ID of the sequence that applies to that invoice
2. check if the value of move_name matches with the last value generated by that sequence
3. if so, delete the invoice and subtract one from the next value of the sequence

Could someone help to highlight how could those 3 steps be achieved (specially the first one).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer to your first query:

Query: How to identify ID of the sequence that applies to that invoice?

Code:

```py
@api.multi
    def unlink(self):
        for invoice in self:
            if invoice.state not in ('draft', 'cancel'):
                raise UserError(_('You cannot delete an invoice which is not draft or cancelled. You should refund it instead.'))
            elif invoice.move_name:
                print "movename", invoice.move_name
                if invoice.journal_id.sequence_id:
                    sequence_id = invoice.journal_id.sequence_id.id
                    print sequence_id
                raise UserError(_('You cannot delete an invoice after it has been validated (and received a number). You can set it back to "Draft" state and modify its content, then re-confirm it.'))
        return super(AccountInvoice, self).unlink()
```

I am a little confused with your 2nd and 3rd question because, Consider there are 5 invoices validated / in open state and you want to delete `invoice no:3`. So as per your requirement you will check if the value of move_name matches with the last value generated by the identified sequence and if it matches you will subtract `1` from the next_value of the sequence.

So the next_value of the sequence will become `5` and when you create another invoice the sequence number will get duplicated as `invoice no:5` which will violate the unique constraint of sequences.

If you want your users to delete only the last created invoice then no problem.

So think about it and I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: I want users to delete only the last created invoice. It is a fair trade between not allowing them to delete invoices (as per accounting standards/legislation in most countries) and provide them some room to fix mistakes.